# How can I run my python scripts on a windows machine without installing extra libraries?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, selenium

I'm working on a python script but it uses a library called Selenium to perform most of its tasks. This script needs to be able to run in a windows environment and I can't go through the trouble of installing Selenium on every machine that I decide to run this script on. I've heard of py2exe but haven't tried it out and am not sure if it will help here. Will I be able to run my script without having to install selenium when using py2exe? It doesn't seem like it would work since selenium isn't built into python.

I'd like to be able to run this script on Windows without having to install python but I'll be satisfied if I can get it to work without having to install selenium. I'm not sure how possible this is and I'm actually fairly new to developing in python so I don't know if this idea will work out.

Actually, other people will be using this script and it would be best if they don't have to go through the trouble of installing python and the selenium library just to use the script. They aren't exactly familiar with python or programming in general, so installing selenium could be a problem for them. I'd like to make the use of my script as user friendly as possible.

The script mainly deals with automating a website. I understand that this can be done in vbs and it would be better in vbs for windows but I've already made it in python and don't want to go through the trouble of re-writing it in vbs, since I've already spent a lot of time on this already.

I've tried many Google searches and can't find much about this topic which leads me to believe it's not possible. The closest solution I've found is py2exe but will it still work if my script uses a library not built into python?(selenium)

I'm sorry if this question was kind of nooby, I'm just trying to learn. I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: have you looked at the documentation? http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions

Comment: I've answered your question below, but to further comment I'd like to state that the goal of pyinstaller, py2exe, cx_freeze is to create a binary file that includes the python library and any script includes so that the binary can be distributed without the need for those resources to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) will build an executable that includes python so that python will not need to be installed on any extra computers. When you build the executable with py2exe you can include or exclude modules in your build.

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is another good module for building executables, it will automatically bundle any includes. Like py2exe you can bundle everything into one executable, include extra data files, hide console windows and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can include external libraries in py2exe

From the [py2exe FAQ](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ),

**How does py2exe decide which modules you need?**

To determine which modules should go in the final .exe file, py2exe does a recursive search of the script that you are packaging to find its dependencies and, in turn, all of their dependencies. This process is written so that it can output extensive debugging information, showing you which modules convinced py2exe to include which other modules. To display this debugging trace, run the py2exe "module finder" code standalone with at least one -d option to turn on "debugging":